# What's the best way to handle basic authentication in an Opentest test involving public URLs?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, opentest

I´m trying to automate a web test in opentest with a public Url which uses basic authentication

When i try to pass credentials in url like this:

`https://username:password@url.com/`

Steps finish ok, but the next steps of the test dont work properly, and in the end, log show me diferents 401 error.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`

How can I include basic authentication in test web browsing?

I trying to test a website with basic authentication